# return value of XMLHttpRequest is not same as manually observing the website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

As the title says - I'm not able to retrieve the same data as what I am seeing.

I'm trying to parse/load an external website using `XMLHttpRequest` (just checking if a few values exists). When I observe the website using Chrome F12 "Elements" tab part of the html looks as following:

```
<li class="mail">
  <a href="my-stuff">My stuff<span class="notification">New</span></a>
</li>
```

If I right click the browser and press "View source" I will instead see this:

```
<li class="mail">
  <a href="my-stuff">My stuff</a>
</li>
```

Note the lack of the `Span`-element. This is also the same as what is retrieved by the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Why is this and is there some way to access the first `HTML`-snippet? Since that's the only thing I'm trying to access here. I'm guessing it's created after page load or something (via javascript), but how can I access that instead?

Thank you!

(I can't provide you with the webpage I'm testing this on)

EDIT: I'm doing this for a Chrome extension. Is there any way to load a page in the background (not show it) and wait for all javascripts to execute on the page and then get the "final" generated HTML?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing it, I'm guessing the span is inserted with javascript, but who knows ?

Comment: The `span` is probably added via Javascript

Comment: As I've stated in the question. I assumed as much, and asked if it's possible to retrieve it somehow..?